# Index Error in Python Program

Tags: python-3.x

I am trying to create a program which tells me if a number's square has different digits.

I have an "Index Error" in the really long "if" line. How do I fix it?

```
a= 4486659

f= (a**2)

s= str(f)

for num in range (1089):
    if s[6]==s[7] or s[6]==s[8] or s[6]==s[9] or s[6]==s[10] or s[6]==s[11] or s[6]==s[12] or s[6]==s[13] or s[6]==s[14] or s[6]==s[15] or s[7]==s[8] or s[7]==s[9] or s[7]==s[10] or s[7]==s[11] or s[7]==s[12] or s[7]==s[13] or s[7]==s[14] or s[7]==s[15] or s[8]==s[9] or s[8]==s[10] or s[8]==s[11] or s[8]==s[12] or s[8]==s[13] or s[8]==s[14] or s[9]==s[10] or s[9]==s[11] or s[9]==s[12] or s[9]==s[13] or s[9]==s[14] or s[9]==s[15] or s[10]==s[11] or s[10]==s[12] or s[10]==s[13] or s[10]==s[14] or s[10]==s[15] or s[11]==s[12] or s[11]==s[13] or s[11]==s[14] or s[11]==s[15] or s[12]==s[13] or s[12]==s[14] or s[12]==s[15] or s[13]==s[14] or s[13]==s[15] or s[14]==s[15]:
        a= a+1
    else:
        print(a)
```

Comment: Yearghh! That is **horrible** code! Use two nested loops. Better still, convert the digits to an array, then convert that to a set. If the set is smaller than the list, there are duplicates. And what the devil is the `num` loop for? You don’t even reference `num`.

Comment: s/array/list/ in above comment.

Answer (score 0):

The index error is because your string s is only 14 chars long, but you try to access s[14] and s[15]

Answer (score -2):

Since you cannot call a nonexistent item in a string, **Try this**:
`if s[6]==s[7] or s[6]==s[8] or s[6]==s[9] or s[6]==s[10] or s[6]==s[11] or s[6]==s[12] or s[6]==s[13] or s[6]==s[14] or s[7]==s[8] or s[7]==s[9] or s[7]==s[10] or s[7]==s[11] or s[7]==s[12] or s[7]==s[13] or s[7]==s[14] or s[8]==s[9] or s[8]==s[10] or s[8]==s[11] or s[8]==s[12] or s[8]==s[13] or s[8]==s[14] or s[9]==s[10] or s[9]==s[11] or s[9]==s[12] or s[9]==s[13] or s[9]==s[14] or s[10]==s[11] or s[10]==s[12] or s[10]==s[13] or s[10]==s[14] or s[11]==s[12] or s[11]==s[13] or s[11]==s[14] or s[12]==s[13] or s[12]==s[14] or s[13]==s[14]:`

Comment: Do you *really* think that a string of 36 conditionals is *good* code? What if the length of the input changed? Junk like this will *not* earn you upvotes on this site.

Comment: Bonus part: there is a duplicate `or`.

Comment: Good catch, @Marvin. That highlights the other big problem with code like this: in addition to being hard to modify, it’s hard to verify its correctness. What if one of the numbers were off? Eventually you might notice some odd behavior, and then after searching through the code, you might realize you were comparing the wrong indices. If you used a simple two-loop structure, errors would be more obvious.